# Changing app setting during the Xcode build process

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have config files (as plist) that contain information used by the app to connect to web services. I  have a file for each of our deployment domains (DEV, PRODUCTION) for obvious reasons(different URLs). So I have plist for each domain in my project e.g
1. myConfig.dev.plist
2. myconfig.prod.plist

I have multiple targets - one for each domain that I am building for. In the target I have scripts that rename the file to myConfig.plist. All these work fine. However I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this instead of having multiple targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XCode 4's new build schemes and have custom environment variables.

```
NSDictionary *environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
NSObject *isDevEnvironment = nil; // set to nil to avoid garbage memory
isDevEnvironment = [environment objectForKey:@"isDevEnvironment"];

if(isDevEnvironment) {
  // Do stuff
} else {
  // Do other stuff
}
```